# Sync Android to the cloud: best practices

Tags: android, mysql, database, web-services, synchronization

I want to two-way sync my Android app's sqlite database to a web app backed by a MySQL database. The web app is RESTful. Now I see two possible ways:

**1. Sync directly to MySQL database**

This seems easiest, but it seems like the storage mechanism of the web service should be abstracted from the synching. Also it feels like a potential security leak, as the MySQL server will need to listen globally instead of on just one IP (that of the web server). Just a gut feeling...

**2. Sync indirectly using web service's API**

I could also sync indirectly by PUTing/POSTing/DELETEing to the web service's URIs. This would nicely abstract the data storage mechanism from the sync and the database server would only need to listen on the web server's IP address.

But I wouldn't be able to use transactions anymore when synching (the db schema has bunch of foreign key relationships), and I can't see any way to deal with failed inserts from primary key collisions this way.

So both have advantages and drawbacks. Which is the way to go? How do professional products do this? Or is there another way that I haven't thought of?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)